# How to open an entire directory of MP3s?

Tags: java, file, directory

I´m new in Java and I was wondering if someone can help me with this:
I have to open a MP3 file, but I don´t want to just open one by one. I want to open an entire directory with all the MP3 files.

Comment: Can you show what effort have you made so far?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the below is helpful for you

```
File dir = new File("mp3 directory path");
File []mp3Files = dir.listFiles();
```

In java, File is An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.